# Span with data-url and method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I have this span and i want to set POST method for data-url but this is not working.

```
<span class="ajax-popup" method="POST" data-url="/profiles/<%= current_user.id %>/change_image?type=avatar">
              <%= image_tag 'back-drop-cam.png' %>
              <p>Change Avatar</p>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `method` use `data-method`

```
<span class="ajax-popup" data-method="POST" data-url="/profiles/<%= current_user.id %>/change_image?type=avatar">
```

In the client side

```
method = $(this).attr("data-method")
```